# Hive Query with multiple Columns in Select and group by one column

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have the below sample image of the dataset and the expected result. What can be the best way to achieve this kind of result in a dataset with a billion records. 
Should we use the intermediate temporary tables or in 1 Query.

Req:-
Get all the records for the SNs which has more than 2 records in the table and Show only the records where the Price is 100

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  `sn` string, 
  `itemA` string, 
  `itemB` string, 
  `price` int)

insert into table test values ('1','A','D',100),('1','B','E',100),('1','C','F',200),('2','A','D',100),('2','C','F',200);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by sn) as cnt
      from test t
     ) t
where cnt > 2 and price = 100;
```